# Como trocar o color a cada objeto renderizado no opengl C++ com shaders?

Tags: c++, opengl

Estou aprendendo agora VBOs e VAOs, e não consigo desenhar objetos de cores diferentes, eles são renderizados com a mesma cor. Tentei utilizar uniform mas não consegui fazer funcionar, como posso fazer isso?

fragment shader:

```
#version 130
out vec4 color;

void main(){
  color = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

Inicialização do shader:

```
// Set "clearing" or background color
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Black and opaque

    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    GLint vertexShaderId = this->loadAndCompileShader("shader/hello.vp",
                                                      GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLint fragmentShaderId = this->loadAndCompileShader("shader/hello.fp",
                                                        GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    this->programId = this->linkShaderProgram(vertexShaderId, fragmentShaderId);

    // Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
```

E então eu quero desenhar cada objeto de uma cor diferente:

```
// Clear the colorbuffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //load everthing back
    glUseProgram(this->programId);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo1[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vboC[0].data());

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 360);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para utilizar diferentes cores no OpenGL com shaders, você basicamente irá ter duas formas de fazer isso:

- uniform
- buffer

**uniform**: dessa forma você irá definir uma mesma cor para toda uma chamada `draw*`, ou seja, tudo que for desenhado nessa função draw irá utilizar aquela cor definida por uniform, aqui basta fazer o upload da cor via `glUniform3f`, por exemplo, declarar um `uniform vec3 uColor` no fragment shader e atribuir esse valor para a variavel builtin `outColor`, ex:

```
// aplicação
// ...
GLint uniColor = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uColor");
glUniform3f(uniColor, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //cor vermelha
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

```
// fragment shader
uniform vec3 uColor;

out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(uColor, 1.0);
}
```

**buffer**: através do buffer é possível inserir qualquer informação que deseja para que seja desenhado posteriormente escolhendo a cor por vértice, sendo possível desenhar as cores de um prisma por exemplo. Nesse caso você precisa adicionar as informações de cores nos vértices, provavelmente seu array de vértices do triangulo está parecido com isso:

```
// vértices organizados em:
// X, Y,
// X, Y,
// X, Y
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    0.0f,  0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f
};
```

para adicionar as informações de cores por vértices faça assim:

```
// vértices organizados em:
// X, Y, R, G, B,
// X, Y, R, G, B,
// X, Y, R, G, B
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    0.0f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

No upload não vai mudar nada em `glBufferData`, porém vc precisa dizer como cada informação está organizada no buffer, usando a função `glVertexAttribPointer`, para cada informação haverá uma chamada da função, como temos 2 informações (posição e cor), deve-se chamar essa função 2 vezes.

```
// aplicação
// ...
// a informação posição possui 2 valores, a cada 5 espaços inicia-se um novo vértice, começando pelo index 0
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

// ...
// a informação cor possui 3 valores, a cada 5 espaços inicia-se um novo vértice, começa ignorando os 2 primeiros valores (pq são as informação de posição)
glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
```

eses valores são capturados pelo vertex shader e devem ser repassados para o fragment shader, só então serão utilizados:

```
//vertex shader
in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;

out vec3 Color;

void main()
{
    Color = color;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

```
fragment shader
in vec3 Color;

out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);
}
```

OpenGL é ultra baixo nível, então as coisas não são tão simples de serem feitas, deixo aqui dois links que podem te ajudar bastante, infelizmente conteúdo em português nessa área é quase inexistente.

[open.gl](https://open.gl/drawing)

[learnopengl](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle)